# Is it possible to un-invert the Y-axis on the camera on Driv3r?

Tags: xbox, driv3r

Driv3r (or Driver 3) was a huge bomb, for a lot of valid reasons, and one of the things that irks me the most is that the camera's Y-axis is inverted, and there is no way to change it...or is there? Is it at all possible to set the Y-axis to normal in Driv3r on the original Xbox? I've looked in the settings multiple times and it doesn't seem to be there, but perhaps there is some way? (Honestly, I doubt there is but I'm desperate)

Answer (score 2):

I found this information,  hope this helps you.

The NXOE update allows you to set inverted Y axis automatically for EVERY game at the system OS level, using the Xbox Accessories app. Here's how:

- If you don't use Kinect, you can find the Xbox Accessories app by pressing left on the Dpad, then choose the Gear icon for Settings, then in the Settings choose Ease of Access at the bottom left, then choose Button Mapping. This will open an app with a thumbstick icon on the splash screen. Alternatively if you have the Kinect, just say "Xbox, go to Xbox Accessories."
- In the Xbox Accessories app, make sure your controller is connected to the console, then choose Configure.
- In the Manage Configuration screen, tick the box for Invert Right Stick Y Axis. Then choose Done to save your changes.

And voilà, your right stick controls will now automatically be inverted in EVERY game, including Xbox 360 backwards compatible games.

IMPORTANT - It's worth noting that this change takes place within the system-OS and the controller software, not in the settings for the actual games you're playing. Basically the Xbox itself is inverting the vertical input for the stick.

- This means if you enable this setting, you should NOT choose inverted Y in the options menu for whichever game you're playing. If you do, the game's inverted controls will then be processed inverted by the Xbox setting, canceling each other out.
- This also means that you may experience some weird issues in games which use the right stick for purposes other than aiming or camera positioning. The right stick signal will be inverted everywhere in the game, including in menu screens.

Comment: Hi @icortazar
You know, that this question is about "original Xbox"? This question is neither about "Xbox 360" nor "Xbox One".

Comment: Oh my bad, i didn't know that sorry